# Gradle >=4.6: using java-library & java plugins simultaneously in multi-module build

Tags: gradle

Since Gradle 4.6:

- https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation
- https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#compile/runtime-scope-separation-in-pom-consumption

new configurations were added: `api` (only in `java-library` plugin) & `implementation` (defined by both).

In multi-module project I have several "core" modules that act as internal libraries and sometimes need to pass exposed compile time dependencies via `api` configuration.

Previously we applied `java` plugin recursively:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

To be purist we can apply `java-library` plugin to "library" modules  and `java` plugin to "end-application" modules.

What if we just put:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
}
```

**NOTE** With proper naming schema (we don't have one) it is possible to do selectively:

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.startsWith('lib-')) {
        apply plugin: 'java-library'
    } else {
        apply plugin: 'java'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It's not really clear what is the question/problem here: the approach with applying the plugin selectively based on project name should work. Did you test it?  (note that `java-library` plugin extends `java plugin` : so you don't need to apply explicitly `java` plugin when you apply `java-library` )

Comment: To be clear: what is the hard from applying both plugins simultaniuosly? It is not convenient to apply selectively.

Comment: Ideally, as you said, you should apply `java-library` plugin only to "library" modules and not "end-application" modules; but since `java-library` extends `java` plugin, you can also apply this plugin to "end application". In these "application" modules you will not use `api` configuration but `implementation`.

Comment: so you can simply apply `java-library` plugin on all your subprojects   `subprojects { apply plugin: 'java-library' }`

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Can you add answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java-library` plugin "expands" the base `java` plugin, so you can simply apply `java-library` plugin to all your sub-projects, this will automatically apply `java` plugin.

As you mentioned, the ideal/purist way would be to apply `java-library` plugin only on "library" projects, but you can still apply this plugin to "end application" modules and this will work (of course in such modules you would use `implementation` configuration and not `api` as it would not make sense).

Another approach would be to apply the needed plugin directly in sub-projects build script and not globally from the root project build; you would not need to define a "naming schema" in this case.